# C# technique for determining if a computer is operating on battery power?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, battery

I've found a number of API's that can help determine how much charge (percentages, charge estimates, etc) - mostly in WMI

in my application, I'd like to know if the computer is currently powered by battery,  not the status of the battery.  in short, I'd like special behavior when not plugged in

is there such an API?  I'm happy with a win32 API to pinvoke if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Boolean x =(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus == 
       PowerLineStatus.Offline);
```

Also check [SystemInformation.PowerStatus Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace there is a `SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus` enum which you can use:

```
switch (SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus)
{
    case BatteryChargeStatus.Charging:
         break; //do nothing
    default:
        //code here. The battery isn't charging so it isn't plugged in
}
```

That's it